# inserção de coluna através de Série python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ipython-notebook

Possuo uma serie coletada de uma coluna do `dataframe`. Necessito criar colunas com cada uma dessa serie. Por exemplo:

```
serie = []
    for s in serie:
        df.insert(loc=0,column=serie,value='int')
```

- colunas: A B C D E
- serie: F G H I J
- depois da inserção: A B C D E F G H I J

Não consegui usar o `insert`. Qual outra forma poderia se usar para criar do resultado da serie uma coluna de cada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserção de colunas em um dataframe pode ser feita de duas formas.

Criando novas colunas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
serie = 'F G H I J'.split(' ')
for s in serie:
    df[s] = []

print(df)
```

Fazendo um merge de outro banco:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns='A B C D E'.split(' '))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns='F G H I J'.split(' '))
print(df.join(df2))
```

Importante notar que o index 0 é o index da primeira observação, não o nome das colunas. Daí o erro no seu código.

Comment: obrigado, tudo certo